# How Does a User Interact with HTML Table Cell <td>?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm working with the following code for a web page.  On the page itself, a user is able to double-click a cell in a table (the `<td>` in the code below), and enter a value.

Is there an attribute, or a part, of this HTML that indicates that a user can interact with this `<td>` element?  Or does this functionality come from another source (like Javascript)?

```
<tr class="ig_290640c5_r2" id="uwgBulkImportList_r_1" style="height: 20px;" alt="true Object="[object Object]">
  <td class="" id="uwgBulkImportList_rc_1_0" Object="[object Object]" unselectable="on" _hasMouse="false">
    <nobr>
      Text - Empty Text Node
```

Comment: Show us some JS as well.  If you want, you can create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQ9Lq/) that will demo your example

Comment: Put the table cell in edit mode and inspect it with your browsers development tools. Maybe there is an `<input>` dynamically inserted or the cell has `contenteditable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML has no indication of `contenteditable` or any attribute, element that would make the `td` be able to take input. My best guess from what you've given, is that it's done via JavaScript.

In the JavaScript, there may be a function like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('td. [some properties] ').each(function() {
        $(this).attr( { 'contenteditable': 'contenteditable' } );
        // or attach an <input> field
    } );
} );
```

That's my best guess, but take it with a grain of salt as that is just speculation.

Comment: Thanks, @geoff!  That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have JavaScript that looks for clicks on the table and then offers the option to edit a certain cell based on the click location.

Would you be able to show us the JavaScript code?